# Grails: How to know which command is being executed, from BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, build, command

Is it possible to know which command is being executed from the BuildConfig.groovy file, in order to change build config depending on the command? For example, if 'schema-export' then do not include 'Foo' library and so on?
I'm using Eclipse and I am running rails cmd from eclipse.

EDIT: after trying out Shashank solution I added details on the fact that I am using Eclipse.

By printing the 'sun.java.command' property I think that my Eclipse installation(Indigo Service Release 2 + Grails IDE 3.5 plugin) is rewriting the command launched to

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess --conf Y:\grails-2.4.4\/conf/groovy-starter.conf --classpath /C:/Program Files/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1764/1/.cp/;/C:/Program Files/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1766/1/.cp/ --is14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked upon it and yes, it is absolutely possible.

Inside anywhere in BuildConfig, you can write something like this:

```
String command = System.getProperty("sun.java.command")

if (command.contains("run-app")) {
    compile (":hibernate:3.6.10.18")  // example to install hibernate while running the app
} else if (command.contains("test-app")) {
    compile (":hibernate:3.6.10.14")  // some other version for test cases
}
```

Or for your example:

```
compile (":some-plugin:2.3") {
    if (command.contains("export-schema")) {
        excludes "foo"
    }
}
```

That property will give you output like this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/conf/groovy-starter.conf --classpath   --offline run-app
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems that in eclipse the command is different from what one should expect. In fact there is no trace of 'schema-export', i.e. the original command. I think yours is the right solution if outside of eclipse.

Comment: Yes, this solution is working fine for me when I run a terminal. You can still do that with eclipse. Just print all system properties and search for your command and then see the System property which holds the command being executed.

Comment: I tried, but none of the properties seems to contains the name of the command

Comment: @Andrea I tried this in GGTS (same as eclipse) and I'm getting the command value as specified.

Comment: So maybe it's something with my eclipse or grails plugin installation.

Comment: It seems that the command is rewritten by eclipse to something like: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess --conf Y:\grails-2.4.4\/conf/groovy-starter.conf --classpath /C:/Program Files/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1764/1/.cp/;/C:/Program Files/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1766/1/.cp/ --is14

Comment: Okay. Another thing you can try by running another command other than **export-schema** and see if you find any pattern. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm accepting this solution because is correct for the 'run-app' command. 'schema-export' and 'dbm-generate-changelog' behave differently and the name of the cmd is not found in the java property. Therefore I will include the library only if 'run-app' command is launched, which suits my needs for the moment. Thank you!!

Comment: The problem is that I have found no way to tell if a 'refresh-dependencies' command has been launched too, leaving me with the same problem.
I think that the best thing to do is, sadly, to add and remove the dependency manually before launching the commands.

Comment: Okay, are you manually firing those commands or using some script or shell alias?

Comment: In Eclipse, ctrl-shift-alt + G brings the grails command line. Then I type the command like '(grails is implicit) dev schema-export'. For refresh dependencies I use the Eclipse interface directly (right click on project's name etc..)

Comment: Okay awesome. There is still an option. When you configure your grails commands in Eclipse, pass the environment variable like **-DexcludeFoo=true dev schema-export** (or whatever system property name you prefer) and then check it in your `BuildConfig.groovy` like: `if (System.getPropety("excludeFoo")) {}`. I'm giving you a very small example. You can pass any string, integer or boolean from command line and then make use of it throughout the code.